# Python - Access a class from a list using a key

Tags: python, class

Is there any way to make a list of classes behave like a set in python?

Basically, I'm working on a piece of software that does some involved string comparison, and I have a custom class for handling the strings. Therefore, there is an instance of the class for each string.

As a result, I have a large list containing all these classes. I would like to be able to access them like `list[key]`, where in this case, the key is a string the class is based off of (note: the string will never change once the class is instantiated, so it should be hashable).

It seems to me that I should be able to do this somewhat easily, by adding something like `__cmp__` to the class, but either I'm being obtuse (likely), or I'm missing something in the docs.

Basically, I want to be able to do something like this (Python prompt example):

```
>>class a:
... def __init__(self, x):
...  self.var = x
...
>>> from test import a
>>> cl = set([a("Hello"), a("World"), a("Pie")])
>>> print cl
set([<test.a instance at 0x00C866C0>, <test.a instance at 0x00C866E8>, <test.a instance at 0x00C86710>])
>>> cl["World"]
<test.a instance at 0x00C866E8>
```

Thanks!

*Edit* Some additional Tweaks:

```
class a:
... def __init__(self, x):
...     self.var = x
... def __hash__(self):
...     return hash(self.var)
...
>>> v = a("Hello")
>>> x = {}
>>> x[v]=v
>>> x["Hello"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Hello'
>>> x["Hello"]
```

Comment: A SET uses indexes, not keys.  A dictionary seems to be more what you want, but you're using a passing in a key of a("Hello"), and trying to retrieve it using a different value -- "Hello".

Comment: You should also define \_\_cmp\_\_ method for class __a__ which will be called in the case of hash value collisions.

Comment: Please use UpperCase Names for Classes.  Please inherit from object.  Like this: `class A(object)`.  It will make many things easier for us to read and easier for you to figure out, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a class that behaves a bit like a mapping:

```
class ClassDict(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.classes = {}

  def add(self, cls):
    self.classes[cls.__name__] = cls

  def remove(self, cls):
    if self.classes[cls.__name__] == cls:
      del self.classes[cls.__name__]
    else:
      raise KeyError('%r' % cls)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.classes[key]

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'ClassDict(%s)' % (', '.join(self.classes),)

class C(object):
  pass

class D(object):
  pass

cd = ClassDict()
cd.add(C)
cd.add(D)

print cd

print cd['C']
```

Comment: Hmmmm. It seems like it should work, but when I try to evaluate `key in ClassDict` it fails with a keyerror, and a print statement in the `__getitem__` function shows it's passing a key of `0`.

Comment: Doh - Need to add `__contains__`

Comment: I wound up doing this, since it let me handle some data deduplication issues I was having as well. OTOH, I now have run into problems with the 2gb 32bit memory limit. \*sigh\*

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do:

```
>>> v = MyStr("Hello")
>>> x = {}
>>> x[v.val]=v
>>> x["Hello"]
MyStr("Hello")
```

Why go through all the trouble of trying to create a hand-rolled dict that uses different keys than the ones you pass in? (i.e. "Hello" instead of MyStr("Hello")).

ex.

```
class MyStr(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = str(val)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.val)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.val

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyStr("%s")' % self.val


>>> v = MyStr("Hello")
>>> x = {}
>>> x[str(v)]=v
>>> x["Hello"]
MyStr("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

As I remember "set" and "dict" uses also `__hash__`

From [Python 2.x doc](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> A dictionary’s keys are *almost* arbitrary values. Values that are not [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable), that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Set and dict use the value returned by an object's  `__hash__` method to look up the object, so this will do what you want:

```
>>class a:
... def __init__(self, x):
...  self.var = x
...
... def __hash__(self):
...  return hash(self.var)
```

Comment: When class `a`'s `__hash__(self)` returns the same hash as the string `x`, you get the additional benefit of it making no difference whatsoever whether you do a dict lookup on `a(x)` or `x`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I insert the class into the dictionary?
With `__hash__` defined, trying to add an instance of the class to a dictionary either gets me a syntax error, or a entry in the dict with the key being the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this

```
class A(object):
    ALL_INSTANCES = {}
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.ALL_INSTANCES[self.text] = self



a1 = A("hello")
a2 = A("world")

print A.ALL_INSTANCES["hello"]
```

output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x00B7EA50>
```